# @font-face renders bold in chrome and firefox

Tags: css, font-face, webfonts

I've done quite a bit of searching and came across different solutions for similar questions here on the site but for some reason I am still unable to fix the issue where my @font-face is still bold in chrome and firefox. Renders fine in safari.

My CSS:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Canela Web';
src: url('/fonts/canela/Canela-ThinItalic-Web.eot');
src: url('/fonts/canela/Canela-ThinItalic-Web.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('/fonts/canela/Canela-ThinItalic-Web.woff2') format('woff2'),
url('/fonts/canela/Canela-ThinItalic-Web.woff') format('woff');
font-weight: 100;
font-style: italic;
font-stretch: normal;
}

@font-face {
font-family: 'Canela Web';
src: url('/fonts/canela/Canela-Thin-Web.eot');
src: url('/fonts/canela/Canela-Thin-Web.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('/fonts/canela/Canela-Thin-Web.woff2') format('woff2'),
url('/fonts/canela/Canela-Thin-Web.woff') format('woff');
font-weight: 100;
font-style: normal;
font-stretch: normal;
}

html {
line-height: 1.15;
-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%
}

h1 {
font-family: Canela Web !important;
font-weight: 100
}

h1 {
font-size: calc(35px + 45 * ((100vw - 768px) / 952));
line-height: calc(45px + 45 * ((100vw - 768px) / 952));
letter-spacing: -.5px
}
```

HTML

```
<h1 class="featured-projects__title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua..</h1>
```

Not sure if I am just overlooking something obvious here in my CSS but having some issues getting this resolved for chrome and firefox.

Any help would be appreciated. I can provide a link if needed as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not enough information to troubleshoot. Can you create a working demo?

Comment: Added some addition info.

Comment: Instead of a numeric value, how about setting the font-weight to `lighter`?  Also, PLEASE do not use `!important`.

Comment: replaced numeric value with 'lighter' and removed !important. Still no luck.